# Load remote URL with Greasemonkey and jQuery

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to perform an Ajax query from within a Greasemonkey script, but I'm stuck with not being able to load data from a remote URL. The script only seems to function if the page being viewed is the same domain as the Ajax call. Example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Hello jQuery
// @namespace     http://www.example.com/
// @description   jQuery test script
// @include       *
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("http://www.google.com", function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});

// EOF
```

This user script works perfectly when visiting `google.com`, but it fails with no error or alert on any other domain. What is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `GM_xmlhttpRequest` can do cross-site access, not the normal [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) that jQuery uses.

Comment: But you can still take the responseText and feed it into jQuery if you want to use the usual stuff to parse it: $(responseText)

Answer (score 0):

In Greasemonkey, there is a function called `GM_xmlhttpRequest` for [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). However, it does not comply with the `XmlHttprequest` interface. Hence, it is not possible to use it with jQuery. This works with jQuery 1.5.

jQuery Ajax in Greasemonley then looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/p/',// this even works for cross-domain requests by default
    xhr: function(){ return new GM_XHR(); },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(val){
        ...
    }
});
```

Source: http://www.monperrus.net/martin/greasemonkey+jquery+and+xmlhttprequest+together

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you can't do that. It's called [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Greasemonkey's version of XHR, [GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) is not subject to the same origin policy that prevents XSS.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `load(URL, [data], [func])`.

I have used it in [a sample application](http://sites.google.com/site/spyderhoodcommunity/tech-stuff/jqueryloadurldatafunc), and it loaded Google search for me even though it is on another domain. There is a downside, that a JavaScript security alert will come when you try to access another domain.

I hope it helps!

P.S. I actually tried a non-Google domain and received some errors. But I found, the error was there because the page was not compatible with the response content being received (JavaScript errors, etc). I did find some pages execute successfully, that I created in another domain. So you have to watch out for what kind of content also you load.

Probably, in such a case, loading the content in an iframe would be better for you.